# need multiple fields for a single file while indexing in solr

Tags: solr

I have PDF files and I am using solr to index it and search the content of the files. Since the content of the files do not follow same order, I used to index them considering whole content of the file as text field. I used to index the file using curl command as follows.

```
 curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/[core name]/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=text&commit=true" -F "myfile=@filename.pdf"
```

Now i need multiple fields, For example, suppose I have CV's. I have to index in such a way that skills in the CV should belong to skills field, address in the CV must belong to address field and qualification into the qualification field. 
What changes has to be made? How will I have to index and how I will have to use curl command? I am new to solr. Please help me in brief. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is CV coming from? Is it db table? or a pdf file ? Because if it is pdf file, there is no way for solr to identify what content is address and what is skills !

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide on the set of fields that your documents will have and define them in the file named *schema.xml*. Then, when a new document gets imported you have to map each value to its corresponding field.

See the data-import tool from the documentation: example importing from XML files [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Example%3a_Indexing_wikipedia). The data import tool is a clean way to import documents. An alternative  programmatic way (via JAVA API) to import documents is [SolrJ](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).